# Error while importing mysql database

Tags: database, wamp, fatal-error

I am getting this error while importing database to my local machine.I am using WAMPServer.Can anyone please help me?

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded in 
C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php on line 285
```

and on 285 line `return mysqli_query($link, $query, $method);`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use the MySQL console

```
Go to wampmanager ->  MySQL -> MySQL Console or cmd  mysql.exe -u root on windows from the mysql folder
USE YourDatabase;
SOURCE C:/yourpath/file.sql;
```

**Option 2**

Modify phpmyadmin.conf (alias folder)

```
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Change the size's to what you want

Sample values? (Depends on your need)

```
post_max_size = 750M 
upload_max_filesize = 750M   
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

For answer completeness 
-->If the above doesnt work (it should) then go ahead and 
Add

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = <LargeValue>(5000-6000?);
```

to `phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.inc.php` . 
Dont edit the `config.default.php` directly.

Comment: Thanku @Slartibartfast, may I change the max_execution_time or max_input_time? and to what value? 370?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this at the beginning of your php file

```
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);
```

If you are using WAMP and if the problem is because of it

Increase the `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` file present in `phpmyadmin\apache2` then go to

`C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.4.10.1\libraries` (or change path according to your installation)

and open the `config.default.php` and change value for $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] to 0:

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

this should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanku @Akshay but the problem is in `DBIMysqli.class.php` file

Comment: There will be configuration variable within the phpMyAdmin directory that you can find in libraries\config.default.php called $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] you can set the value of that variable to whatever maximum execution time you need. i hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanku @Akshay for your time :)..but I tried the solution provided by  Slartibartfast and it works :)